# RxDom: Update content of div recursive when an input is changed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-dom

I'm using [Reactive Extension DOM](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM) for listening event from DOM. Currently I meet one problem: I have an input A and div B and div C. Changing input A will affect B, and changing content of B will change content of div C. So, it means: if I change input A, div B and div C will automatically change.

Currently I meet problem: when input A is changed, input B changed successfully but not C. I don't know because RxDom doesn't support changing recursive or because div doesn't have change event. Here is my short code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('test_id');
    var source = Rx.DOM.change(input);
    var subscription = source.subscribe(
            function (x) {
              console.log(x);
            },
            function (err) {
              console.log('Error: ' + err);
            },
            function () {
              console.log('Completed');
            });
```

Obviously I can listen to event of input A and then change C but that is not really the way I want and it looks like a workaround version. Because due to business, div C depends on div B rather than input A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rx will subscribe to the `change` event of the input. `change` event only triggers on actual user input but your value is changed programmatically.

Your problem is: You input into A by yourself, `change` of A is trigger -> subscription on A will be run -> B is changed programmatically -> `change` is not trigger on B -> subscription on B won't run :)

So solution for this is: when you change value of B, you trigger again `change` event manually. You also should note that you must do this on pure javascript, not on jquery. Here is an example code:

```
var event = new Event('change');
div_b_element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Below code will not work. Because RxJS subscribes only to javascript native events, not jquery events. Be carefully because this will cost you long time for debugging.

```
$(div_b_element).trigger( "change" );
```